# Typo3 OnePager load Content with Fluidtemplate

Tags: templates, typo3, typoscript

I'm creating a Typo3 OnePager Website with help of this [Blog Post](http://typo3-4-newbies.blogspot.com/2014/03/onepage-microsite-mit-typo3.html). It loads all the subpages of the root page as sections in the OnePager. This work as explained, but it only loads the content directly from tt_content and not via Fluidtemplate. I want it to load with Fuildtemplate because I have several different templates which can be selected in the backend.

So the whole TS, that loads the content and the template looks like this:

```html
lib.sectionContent = HMENU
lib.sectionContent {
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    NO = 1
    NO {
      doNotLinkIt = 1
      stdWrap >
      stdWrap {
        cObject = COA
        cObject {
          if.value = 4
          if.equals.field = doktype
          if.negate = 1
          10 < temp.titleSectionId
          10.wrap = <section id="|">
          20 = CONTENT
          20 < styles.content.get
          20 {
                table = tt_content
                select.where.field = column
                select.where.wrap = colPos = |
            }
          }
          30 = TEXT
          30 {
            wrap = </section>
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

lib.mainTemplate = FLUIDTEMPLATE
lib.mainTemplate{

        templateName = TEXT
        templateName.stdWrap{
            cObject = TEXT
            cObject{
               data = levelfield:-2,backend_layout_next_level,slide
                override.field = backend_layout
                split {
                    token = pagets__
                    1.current = 1
                    1.wrap = |
            }
        }   
        ifEmpty = contentPage1column
    }

    templateRootPaths {
    10 = {$path.privat}Templates/Page/
    }
    layoutRootPaths {
        10 = {$path.privat}Layouts/Page/
    }
    partialRootPaths {
        10 = {$path.privat}Partials/Page/
    }

}
```

In the template I load the content with

```html
<f:format.raw><f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.sectionContent" data="{column:0}" /></f:format.raw>
```

But when I try to load the FE, then I get this Error:

An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT * FROM `tt_content` WHERE (`tt_content`.`pid` IN (1)) AND (colPos =) AND (`tt_content`.`sys_language_uid` = 0) AND ((`tt_content`.`deleted` = 0) AND (`tt_content`.`t3ver_state` <= 0) AND (`tt_content`.`pid` <> -1) AND (`tt_content`.`hidden` = 0) AND (`tt_content`.`starttime` <= 1546847160) AND ((`tt_content`.`endtime` = 0) OR (`tt_content`.`endtime` > 1546847160)) AND (((`tt_content`.`fe_group` = '') OR (`tt_content`.`fe_group` IS NULL) OR (`tt_content`.`fe_group` = '0') OR (FIND_IN_SET('0', `tt_content`.`fe_group`)) OR (FIND_IN_SET('-1', `tt_content`.`fe_group`))))) ORDER BY `sorting` ASC': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND (`tt_content`.`sys_language_uid` = 0) AND ((`tt_content`.`deleted` = 0) AN' at line 1

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You are querying a *templateName*! Why is it that complex to get a simple name? It looks like you mix name and content.

Comment: yes you're right. I've change the TS, so that the lib.sectionContent should load the content and then the lib.mainTemplate should get the template name from the backend. I updated it in my post. I assume the thing that I got wrong is the part wehre I actually load the content with styles.content.get but im not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you can see there is no value for the column in the query:

```
[...] WHERE (tt_content.pid IN (1)) AND (colPos =) AND [...]
                                                 ^
```

and when you inspect where you build up your query:

```
lib.sectionContent = HMENU
lib.sectionContent {
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    NO = 1
    NO {
      stdWrap {
        cObject = COA
        cObject {
          20 = CONTENT
          20 {
            select.where.field = column
            select.where.wrap = colPos = |
            :
```

you can see the context is a TMENU. There you have a `pages` record as current data. And in `pages` there is no field `column`.

you might change your `lib.sectionContent` to a COA with the first entry to store the 'parameter' `column` into a register, which you later can use as `register:column`

```
lib.sectionContent = COA
lib.sectionContent {
  10 = LOAD_REGISTER
  10 {
    column.cObject = TEXT
    column.cObject.field = column
  }
  20 = HMENU
  20 {
    :
          select.where.data = register:column
          select.where.wrap = colPos = |
    :
```

Comment: Thanks, now the content shows on the FE. The Problem is, that it repeats the content from the root page as many times as there are sub pages. For example I have 3 subpages below the root page. So it displays 3 times the content of the root page, not the subpages. I guess that it loads the content from the DB. Do I need to tell TS that I need the content with a certain UID?

Comment: in your select (inspect your `20` in the TSOB) you have no individual `pid` value, which should be the `pid`of the ***current*** page (TMENU context)

Comment: So how would I be able to create a OnePager with Fuildetemplate? I assume it is possible? Do I need another Object instead of TMENU? Or do I create to OnePager Style with View Helpers in the Template?

Comment: you need to change the 'select' property. use the TSOB to inspect the entry for `pidInList`. you need something like `pidInList.field = uid` (you are in context of the 'current' page of your menu)

Comment: So I've inspected the pidInList entry. And it showed me three entries where pidInList shows up. tt_content.menu_categorized_content.dataProcessing.10.pidInList.data = leveluid : 0, then tt_content.menu_section.dataProcessing.10.dataProcessing.20.pidInList.field = uid and lastly tt_content.menu_section_pages.dataProcessing.10.dataProcessing.20.pidInList.field = uid. I assume its the first one I need to change, but idk how.

Comment: Don't tamper with these occurences of `pidInList`. I think your select has no explicit `pidInList`, so the default value (`this`) is used. As you want content from another page than `this` you must insert a value. just add  `lib.sectionContent.20.1.NO.stdWrap.cObject.20.select.pidinlist.field = uid` to your typoscript.

Comment: Still showing the content of the landing page multipletimes. I've added the code to my TS, tried a couple different PID's but it always shows the content of the current page. Is it even possible to load the content of different pages with the template which I selected in the BE?

Comment: Inspect your changes with TSOB (maybe I made a typo and your change is ignored as it points to unused typoscript.

Comment: with this construct you have no page templates for the subpages as you only render the CEs. you might modify your rendering if you gather further information from the 'current' page and use it in conditions (fluid or `.stdWrap.if`)